# Why would you duplicate a filedescriptor and never use it?

Tags: c, shell, unix

Here is the part:

```
extern fin;
char line[64];

if (argc<2 || ttyn(0)!='x') {
        write(1, "goto error\n", 11);
        seek(0, 0, 2);
        return;
}
seek(0, 0, 0);
fin = dup(0);
```

Notice that in the whole code "fin" only occurs in the part above. **So why would you duplicate the std input** *(which in this case is a file/script),* **store it in fin and never use it?**

You can find the whole code here http://v6shell.org/history/goto.c with Syntax-Highlighting here http://pastebin.com/uAvANLdR

PS. This is K&R-C. The used command dup is described here: http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/2/dup

**UPDATE:**
I found out, that it is actually needed for the command getchar. Look here http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/3/getchar

**But I still don't get why you need it. Can someone tell now?**

Comment: Note that `fin` is an `extern` variable; it might be used elsewhere.

Comment: Can you imagine, where it could be used and why? This code is the source code of unix command goto.

Comment: Have you tried searching for it in the code?

Comment: It is used for the command getchar! Look here: http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/3/getchar But I still don't get why you need it.

Comment: perhaps you'll need it prior to call a function that can close the other file descriptor, so you have a live copy of the descriptor.  As it's been commented, `fin` is declared as `extern`, and it can be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the man page of getchar(3)

http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/3/getchar

there is this little block stating:

> Associated with this routine is an external variable called
>   fin, which is a structure containing a buffer such as
>   described under getc (III).

So if we have a closer look at getc(3)

http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/3/getc

we see that:

```
struct buf {
  int fildes;     /* File descriptor    */
  int nleft;      /* Chars left in buffer */
  char *nextp;    /* Ptr to next character */
  char buff[512]; /* The buffer */
};
```

The code in goto.c now does a hack by telling the compiler that "fin" is of type int. Actually "fin" has the type struct buf, but as "int filedes;" is the first member of the struct that code performs actually the same as:

```
extern struct buf fin;

...

seek(0, 0, 0);
fin.fildes = dup(0);
```

As I said it is a hacky solution but the code seems pretty old anyway with all that gotos in it.

Comment: The original source can be found here: http://minnie.tuhs.org/Archive/PDP-11/Distributions/research/Dennis_v6/v6src.tar.gz  The source for `getchar()` is in `s4/getchr.s`.  If the timestamps in the tarball are correct, the source files are from 1975.  So no surprise that the code doesn't follow what would be considered "best practices" today - the code is from the dawn of mini-computing.

Comment: just the PDP-11 in the path indicates a very obsolete piece of code.  And the Dennis_v6 probably reflects a unix v6 release.

Answer (score 1):

One reason I could think of is that if fd 0 (stdin) is a reading end of a pipe(2) and gets closed later (i.e. after a call to execve(2)), then anyone trying to write to that pipe will still be blocked and will not get a SIGPIPE signal.

Comment: I just looked over the code and I came to the conclusion, that this may just be used from outside. It has to be defined somewhere, otherwise this program would not link.